# Creating a table using hourly readings from a current table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, create-table

I have a table that is being used to log values every second

```
datetime                float   float
25/02/2013 08:18:56     6       147
```

I need to create a table that has a single row for each hour over the last month.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What sql-server version are you using?

Comment: What do you want the "single row for each hour" to look like?  A randomly selected row for that hour?  The first row?  A row that adds up the columns for the hour?  And do you have two columns named float????

Comment: Why do you need to "create a table" based on data that already exists, rather than just run a report against the original data? Are you creating redundant data to solve a different problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just query the table for what you want?

The following query will return the first reading in every hour:

```
select <columns you want here>
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(datetime), month(datetime), day(datetime),
                                             datepart(hour, datetime)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

You can put this into a table, adding the `into` statement after the `select`.